# How to remove the guardian temple's mining fatigue animation?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever you are in the vicinity of a Guardian temple, the texture of a guardian will scroll past your screen with an eerie sound. I never intentionally stray by a temple, but from time to time, either by traveling over one by boat or entering mines/tunnels underneath one, the animation (and sound) will play, genuinely scaring me and making me jump (I'm jumpy, okay?). I don't need or really want this animation, so is there any way to remove this animation, without removing the textures for other mobs (like the guardian)?

(as an extra note, whatever solution must also work for multiplayer servers, not just singleplayer)

Answer (score 2):

I originally thought that this could be done with a resource pack and was going to write up a quick tutorial explaining which files to edit, but it turns out there isn't a good solution to this.

There's no special texture for the elder guardian ghostly effect. It's actually a transparent version of the elder guardian texture, and uses the same model:
[image: same model]

So, even if you did know the exact file to change, you'd be changing the texture of the actual elder guardian, which I would guess is not something you want to do.

Technically, this is still possible by changing the elder guardian's texture, then having all elder guardians in your world by invisible, and instead use an armorstand with an item that has the elder guardian model (And constantly teleport it to the invisible elder guardian). However, this would mean the swimming and spikes would not longer be animated (logically).

So to conclude, there's no good way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Without a little work, this can't be done. You can, however, create a resource pack where the sound file and image for the effect is blank. You will still get mining fatigue, but you won't be scared.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: You'll have to look it up, I'm not super knowledgeable in that process.

Comment: Oddly enough, there is no separate texture file for the ghostly slider effect, it uses the same texture and model as the actual elder guardian, just transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I know a way: turn off screen animations then turn off hostile mob sounds. You will still see the image but not the sound, I understand. It makes me jump every time.

Comment: Hello, can you specify on your answer? You can add pictures or a video to show what you mean.